# Retrieve Folder Older than Date Based On folder Name

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, find

I have a set of snapshots.   Each snap shot resides in a `accountname` folder, and each snap shot is named with a date format as: `YYYY-MM-DD-accountname`

How can I retrieve the name of the "snap shot folder" where it is older than 2 days old?  (The `2017-05-*` directories)

Folder structure such as:

```
/home/snapshots
    /home/snapshots/account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-01-account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-02-account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-03-account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-04-account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-05-account1
        /home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-06-account1
    /home/snapshots/account2
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-01-account1
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-02-account1
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-03-account1
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-04-account1
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-05-account1
        /home/snapshots/account2/2017-05-06-account1
```

For instance... I want to list `/home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-01` through `/home/snapshots/account1/2017-05-04`, given that today is 05/06/2017 (US), and vice-versa for `account2`

I thought `find /home/snapshots/ -type d -mtime +2 -exec -ls -la {} \;` may do the trick, but that returned me all folders older directories older than 2 days... and adding `maxdepth 1` returned nothing...

Comment: If you want to delete when it is `2` days old, then with `find`, you actually asking to delete files **older than 2 days old** (older than 2, 24 hour periods old) You actually want `find /home -type d -name "snapshots" -mtime +2 -execdir rm -r '{}' +` (using `execdir` instead of `exec`, slightly more efficient execute in target directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment above, the reason you are having problems is you want to search within `/home` and then select and delete the `snapshots` directories found if they are more than two days old. With `-execdir`, it would be

```
find /home -type d -name "snapshots" -mtime +2 -execdir rm -r '{}' +
```

Let me know if you have problems. (also, there is no need to use `ls -la` within `find`, the `-printf` option provide you complete output format control without spawning a multiple separate subshells for each `ls` call, see `man find`)

**note:** you should quote `'{}'` to protect against filenames with whitespace, etc.

**Edit**

Sorry I misread your question, Obviously if you only want to delete the `account*` subdirectories of each `snapshots` directory, then the search path of `/home/snapshots` is fine and you then include the `account*/*account*` designator as @BroSlow correctly caught below.

Comment: Think `kevin` wanted to delete directories matching `/home/snapshots/account*/*-account*`, not the entire snapshots directory. Also, you don't need to quote `{}`, the shell isn't doing the expansion.

Comment: I experience complete dyslexia or bi-polar schizophrenia when I read the question. You are correct -- good catch, noted in edit.

Comment: yeah, this is also what I get for asking a question while coming up with ideas after a few beers... lol

Comment: I tried the above, with just a `ls` (so I don't actually delete anything yet), but it still returns me everything inside the `/home/snapshots/*` directories.  My end game is to have a viable way to only keep the 2 latest snapshots of my `lxc` containers... so in order to do so, I do need to get a list of only the `/home/snapshots/*` directories.  From which I will pull the name, so I can delete the older snapshots through `lxc`

Comment: So... I really only need a `better` way to parse the "end-folder" name and compare it to todays date....

Comment: @Kevin Something like `find /home/snapshots/ -path '/home/snapshots/account*/*-account* -type d -mtime +2 -prune -exec -ls -la {} \;`